# For loop not iterating through whole array

Tags: c++, arrays, twitter

So I'm still pretty new at C++ and I created this loop to go through a long list of tweets that I have in a .csv file, that I imported into an array of 30,000. Now the HashAll function is being used to look through each tweet and find where there is a # and then copying the word into a new string and then putting that new string into a new array to collect the hashtags used. The problem is, every time I test my code I get a core dump and I can't figure out why. Here is my code below. Thank you for any help!

```
void AllTweets::HashAll(){
    int counter=0;
    for(int i=0; i<30000;i++){ //loop to looks are every tweet indv.
            string singleTweet = Tweet[i];
            int x = singleTweet.length();
        for(int j=0;j<x;j++){
            string newHash;
            if(singleTweet[j]=='#') {
                    int k=j;
                while(singleTweet[k]!=' '){
                    newHash=newHash+singleTweet[k];
                    k=k+1;
                }
                HashtagAll[counter]=newHash;
                counter=counter+1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: ignore my note haha sorry for the misspelling.

Comment: If a hashtag is at the end of a tweet there might not be a space after it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem is that you always expect to find a space after the hashtag word and while searching for it in the `while()` loop, you never test to see if you are not extrapolating the size of the string.

A simple solution would be to include that test in the loop:

```
while (singleTweet[k] != ' ' && k < x)
{
    newHash = newHash + singleTweet[k];
    k++;
}
```

However I urge that this code should be reconsidered, there are more things happening here than meet the eye. Every time you increment `newHash` by 1 character, you are forcing it to relocate to a new space in memory that can fit its new size, creating unnecessary, time consuming work, and fragmenting memory all over the place, not to mention that this is not how to work with strings in C++.

The class `std::string` is not merely a self-resizing buffer, it offers a variety of methods for handling text and strings made to make your code objective and your life easier, and you should use them. For example, your method could be rewritten to be more like this:

```
void AllTweets::HashAll()
{
    size_t counter = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 30000; ++i)
    {
        size_t find = 0;
        while ((find = Tweet[i].find("#", find)) != std::string::npos)
        {
            size_t end = Tweet[i].find(" ", find + 1);
            if (end == std::string::npos)
            {
                HashtagAll[counter++] = Tweet[i].substr(find);
                break;
            }

            HashtagAll[counter++] = Tweet[i].substr(find, end - find);
            find = end + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

This code makes use of the `std::string` methods designed to handle this problem, while avoiding redundant work, pointless copying of objects and memory fragmentation.